# What kind of information can the Model access in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Ryan Bates's [first episode on complex forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1), he adds the following to a model:

```
# models/project.rb
has_many :tasks

def task_attributes=(task_attributes)
  task_attributes.each do |attributes|
    tasks.build(attributes)
  end
end
```

I've never thought about this before, but how does the Project model know what "tasks" of which Project instance? Does that come from the has_many association? Is it like, when the project is running and I'm viewing a Project, that's the "active" object so project.rb knows which Project object we're referring to, so it knows that tasks is really some_current_project.tasks? (I'm obviously grasping at straws here.)

Also, if someone would point me to some reference that explains other questions like this one, I'd really appreciate it.

I hope my question is clear. Please ask for more clarification in comments if needed.

Please note: I know that Active Record handles CRUD actions and that objects correspond to rows in tables, etc. Those are just descriptions of what Active Record *is*. I'm looking for how it works when the project is running. I also now the constructs MVC, but I can't seem to find a detailed explanation of what information is sent where with respect to Rails.

Comment: Tasks are related to the Project model, so when tasks are created inside a model, the id automatically set.

Comment: ...automatically set by what? When? Can I change it? If so, how? If not, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Not sure I fully understood your question, feel free to let me know if that's the case.)

A rails model is basically a ruby class that is persisted to a database. So it acts like a normal ruby object for the most part, with some database magic mixed in.

You tell rails which project instance to load (e.g. by providing an `id`), and it loads the data from the database.

Then, when you call `project.tasks` is when the magic happens: the `Project` model has no `tasks` method, so it will trigger ruby's `method_missing` method. This will then load the associated records into model instances and provide access to them via a rails object.

Since a `project` has many `task`s, rails knows it should look into the `tasks` database and load the rows where `project_id` is equal to the `project` model's `id` attribute.

In short, ruby meta-programming and monkey patching possibilities make much of rails' magic possible.

---

(Edit for question on routing.)

When you want to edit project number 13, you go to a URL that looks something like www.mysite.com/projects/13/edit. If you look at `routes.rb` in your `config` directory, you'll see (in Rails3) `resources :projects` what Rails does is set up all sorts of paths for you. Behind the magic, the edit path looks like

```
get '/projects/:id/edit' => 'projects#edit'
```

This basically says "when a user wants to see www.mysite.com/projects/13/edit, send him to the `edit` action in the `projects` controller and set the `id` parameter to the value that's in that place.

Then in your controller, you'll load the appropriate project with

```
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
```

In a similar way, you could do this (this is an dumb example):

In `routes.rb`, put

```
get '/projects/:id/edit_name/:name' => 'projects#edit'
```

And then in you controller

```
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
@project.name = params[:name]
```

So rails basically uses magic to assign values in the URL to params you can work with in your controller. You can read more about routing here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I think you do understand my question correctly. (Sorry it's so confusing.) The part where the id is provided, how does that happen? A previous comment said that's in params... What if you're viewing one project but want to edit the tasks of another project, based on what you're viewing (for some contrived reason)? How do change the id so that project.tasks refers to the right project?

Comment: I updated my answer, as there isn't enough room in a comment.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! I'd forgotten about routes and, while reading your answer, remembered what I had forgotten. That was very helpful. Thanks for your patience.